# Uploaded IPA to apple via Flutter platform return with Missing Purpose reject

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

NSContactsUsageDescription, NSCalendarsUsageDescription, NSAppleMusicUsageDescription,  NSMotionUsageDescription, NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription,Missing Push Notification Entitlement

- I don't ask for this.
- I don't use library that need permissions like that

dio
moor_flutter
provider
intl
alice
encrypt
flutter_launcher_icons

what should I do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step may it help you:

Search in your code if you are asking for any permission that you missed.

If not, then check your third party library.

If still not found any usage of sensitive data then please check third party library again because this may use private sensitive data internally for some processing.